# Customize navbar toggler icon of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to customize the navbar toggler icon of bootstrap with font-awesome but my code is not working why?I'm using font-awesome CDN.

```
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
     <i class="fas fa-navicon" style="color:#fff; font-size:28px;"></i>
</span>
```

This code is showing just 2 white lines on the hamburger toggle icon of bootstrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using BS4x. You just need to reset the default SVG background image and specify your desired alternative in CSS:

```html
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
```

```css3
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: none;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon::before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0c9"; /* fa-bars, fa-navicon */
}
```

`FontAwesome` is for FA < v5, for FA > v5 use `'Font Awesome\ 5 Free'` (afaik)

By that you also avoid dirty inline CSS. Simply apply the needed rules such as `color` and `font-size` to the `.navbar-toggler-icon::before` class.

Comment: Why are we using `.navbar-toggler-icon::before` and not `.navbar-toggler-icon::after`?

Comment: @arantebw, in this case it does not matter, it is just an empty element. So if I have used `:after` you could have asked the opposit. The difference is the stacking order if you have more content in the element, text or sub elements.

Answer (score -1):

There is no `fas fa-navicon` in Font Awesome 5. Use `fas fa-bars` for Font Awesome 5.

You may see the icon reference from w3school [link](https://www.w3schools.com/icons/icons_reference.asp).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
     <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color:#000; font-size:28px;></i>
</span>
```